# List of Currency Symbols in Listings

Tags: listings, unicode, listingsutf8

I'm getting unicode errors when using currency symbols in a listing environment.
I tried to add `\usepackage{textcomp}` but then I'm getting other (bibtex) errors. So maybe there is a cleaner option?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip=half]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=Example, label=lst:example]

currencies = ["£","€","$","¥","¢","₩","§"]


\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89638 (although personally I've found it simpler to use `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` for UTF-8 listings).

Comment: You have to literate all those characters. Please read the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LateX commands to typeset them in listings mode, so you have to escape them. For that, use \lstset. The commands to type them are located in [textcomp](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip=half]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}
}
\begin{document}

This is it in TeX mode: currencies =[\texteuro \textlira \textcent     \textdollar \textyen \textwon \textsection]

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=Example, label=lst:example]
This is it in listings mode:    
currencies = [(*@{\pounds \texteuro \textdollar \textyen \textcent \textwon             \textsection}@*)]   
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```