# Unicode characters in a listing environment are not colorized!

Tags: listings, color, unicode

When using the package `listing`, colorized comments will not yield colorized exotic unicode characters.

[image: exotic unicode characters within a comment are not colorized]

This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

    \usepackage{
        listings,
        color,
        fontspec
    }

    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

    \lstset{
      commentstyle=\color{green},
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,showtabs=false]
        // Comments are green, yet ‘•’ and ‘≤’ are not.
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Colorizing these characters generally works within listing environments:

[image: unicode characters colorized by basicstyle]

```
    \lstset{
      basicstyle=\color{green},
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[showtabs=false]
      Everything is green, even ‘•’ and ‘≤’.
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug? How can I colorize the unicode characters within comments?
I’m using TeXLive 2013 and lualatex.

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: You will have to add the non-ascii letters (this includes the quote characters to `\lst@ProcessLetter` first. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/2388.

Comment: @egreg I’m using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you know what kind of codes (`^^80`, `^^81` etc.) these are in the answer in your link?

Comment: Add more chars in the line starting with `^^^^20ac`. This is the input for the euro sign and reflects it unicode (U+20AC).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, I added the symbols I used. It doesn’t change my output. (After all, the symbols were displayed before.) So this unfortunately does not solve my problem. Thank you, though.

Comment: I tested it: I added `^^^^2022^^^^2264` to the list and it worked fine. The symbols are now green.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, indeed! It now works, I must have made some error before, – I can’t figure it out, what I have done wrong, but now it works. You should post this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the  the non-ascii letters (this includes the quote characters) to \lst@ProcessLetter (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/2388}

```
\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
  ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
  ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
  ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
  ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
  ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
  ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
  ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
  ^^^^2022^^^^2264% add more codes here
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother
```