# listingsutf8 in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, listingsutf8

In order to cope with utf8 listing files, I want to use `listingsutf8`.
However on XeLaTeX i receive the warning:

```
Package listingsutf8 Warning: Package loading is aborted because of missing \pdf@unescapehex.
```

My question is: is the package incompatible with XeLaTex? Is there a workaround? or can we simply use the old `listings` on this engine without the options: `extendedchars` & `literate` and let the engine figure out the encodings.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396.