# Verbatim vs Listings for Thai Font

Tags: fonts, listings, verbatim

I have a problem about `verbatim` and `listings`. I need write some codes by using Thai font but it shows in picture

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH" 
\XeTeXlinebreakpenalty=100
\XeTeXlinebreakskip=0pt plus 1pt
\setmainfont[Scale=1.4]{TH SarabunPSK} % Thai Font
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{enumerate} 
\item one หนึ่ง
\item two สอง
\end{enumerate}     
\end{verbatim}  
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{enumerate}
\item one หนึ่ง
\item two สอง
\end{enumerate}     
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would like to get code like `lstlisting` but font like `verbatim`. How to improve it.

Comment: Because the Thai font you're using isn't installed on my machine, I cannot test this, but simply try to add `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}` to your preamble.

Comment: Thank you. I follow your advice, but Thai font does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution I think it will succeed in your case (I have no Thai font),  you can show  Thai font using `escapeinside` which define two symbols between them you can insert your text.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH" 
\XeTeXlinebreakpenalty=100
\XeTeXlinebreakskip=0pt plus 1pt
\setmainfont[Scale=1.4]{TH SarabunPSK} % Thai Font
\newfontfamily\thaifont{TH SarabunPSK}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, escapeinside={*}{*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{enumerate} 
\item one หนึ่ง
\item two สอง
\end{enumerate}     
\end{verbatim}  
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{enumerate}
\item one *\thaifont{หนึ่ง}*
\item two *\thaifont{สอง}*
\end{enumerate}     
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that there is no typewriter font for thai. You can try the Code2000 font, which is, of course, not a typewriter font, but has all characters:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.4]{TH SarabunPSK} % Thai Font
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Code2000}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH" 
\XeTeXlinebreakpenalty=100
\XeTeXlinebreakskip=0pt plus 1pt

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

    \begin{verbatim}
    \begin{enumerate} 
    \item one หนึ่ง
    \item two สอง
    \end{enumerate}     
    \end{verbatim}  
    \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\small]
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item one หนึ่ง
    \item two สอง
    \end{enumerate}     
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The lstlisting code will only work as long a the thai is on its own (starts with a space). `bccสองccc` would give wrong output ` สองbccccc`. Then you need to declare the chars first,see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/2388.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Follow your comment I experienced another problem of incorrect rendering  (tested with Khmer). Any improvement?