# lstlisting: color LaTeX commands like `\\` or `\!`

Tags: listings

How can I achieve it with lstlisting, that LaTeX commands like `\\` or `\!` are properly highlighted as syntax?
Adding those commands (with or without backslash) to `moretexcs` does not deliver the indented result.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  texcsstyle=*\color{cyan},
  moretexcs={!},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{equation}
  \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\! 2}
\end{equation}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: probably you need to change the catcode... in linstings' manner of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `literate` option to replace desired commands with highlighted ones.

Problem is that, when you use starred `texcsstyle` option, code added to `SelectCharTable` hook, by `tex` aspect (p.152 of listings developers guide), partially overrides code used by `literate` option (p. 137).

If you want `listings` to properly use literate replacement, you need to "rehook" code used by `literate`, after loading `tex` aspect.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\lstset{
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  texcsstyle=*\color{cyan},
  literate=*%
    {\\!}{{\textcolor{cyan}{\textbackslash{}!}}}2
    {\\\\}{{\textcolor{cyan}{\textbackslash{}\textbackslash{}}}}2,
}

% "Rehook" literate char table.
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{SelectCharTable}
    {\ifx\lst@literate\@empty\else
         \expandafter\lst@Literate\lst@literate{}\relax\z@
     \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{equation}
  \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\! 2}
  \gamma!
  \\!
  \\left
\end{equation}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: pdf screen shot]

Of course you can add all replacements, as in [Ismo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267681/70587), just without `¡`s at the beginning.

Comment: @MaxNoe I'm glad I could help.

Comment: The `i`s are [inverted exclamation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_question_and_exclamation_marks) `¡`

Answer (score 2):

So here is another try. Unfortunately it requires a bit of extra markup and is hence unsuitable for reading in a functioning TeX file as a listing.

Of course the ¡ can be replaced by any character that is never needed in the code.

See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/32665) how to use a character with a codepoint larger than 255.

EDIT: Even a space ("\ " in literate) will work.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  texcsstyle=*\color{red},
  extendedchars,
}

\lstset{
  literate=*{¡\\!}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash!}}}{2}
            {¡\\"}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash"}}}{2}
            {¡\\\#}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash\#}}}{2}
            {¡\\\$}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash\$}}}{2}
            {¡\\\%}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash\%}}}{2}
            {¡\\\&}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash\&}}}{2}
            {¡\\'}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash'}}}{2}
            {¡\\(}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash(}}}{2}
            {¡\\)}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash)}}}{2}
            {¡\\*}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash*}}}{2}
            {¡\\+}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash+}}}{2}
            {¡\\,}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash,}}}{2}
            {¡\\-}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash-}}}{2}
            {¡\\.}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash.}}}{2}
            {¡\\/}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash/}}}{2}
            {¡\\:}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash:}}}{2}
            {¡\\;}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash;}}}{2}
            {¡\\<}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash<}}}{2}
            {¡\\=}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash=}}}{2}
            {¡\\>}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash>}}}{2}
            {¡\\?}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash?}}}{2}
            {¡\\[}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash[}}}{2}
            {¡\\\\}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash\textbackslash}}}{2}
            {¡\\]}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash]}}}{2}
            {¡\\\^}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash\textasciicircum}}}{2}
            {¡\\\{}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash\{}}}{2}
            {¡\\|}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash|}}}{2}
            {¡\\\}}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash\}}}}{2}
            {¡\\\~}{{\textcolor{red}{\textbackslash\textasciitilde}}}{2}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  ¡\! ¡\" ¡\# ¡\$ ¡\% ¡\& ¡\' ¡\( ¡\) ¡\* ¡\+ ¡\, ¡\- ¡\. ¡\/ ¡\: ¡\; ¡\< ¡\= ¡\> ¡\? ¡\[ ¡\\ ¡\] ¡\^ ¡\{ ¡\| ¡\} ¡\~
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was easier than I thought.

EDIT: not quite. Of the characters listed in "other" in table 2 of the listings documentation, only !, " and # actually work like this.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  texcsstyle=*\color{cyan},
  alsoletter={!},
  moretexcs={!},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{equation}
  \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\! 2}
\end{equation}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem with this is that `\gamma!` wouldn't highlight `gamma`.

Comment: and that it does not work for   \\