# If texcsstyle star used, opening (closing) square bracket(s) and the same one(s) with leading backslash indistinguishable as listings' delimiters

Tags: listings, delimiters

The following MCE points out that, if used as `listings`' delimiters:

- `[` and `]` (opening and closing square brackets),
- `\[` and `\]` (the same ones preceded with backslash),

cannot be distinguished (the order of the directives doesn't matter).

### Update

As pointed out by Schweinebacke, it is enough to escape the backslash with a backslash. But this trick does not work if the optional star of `texcsstyle` is also used in order to highlight the backslash in front of the control sequence
names. See the updated example.

Do you know:

1. why?
2. how make them distinguishable?

Subsidiary (but maybe related) question: how to color the whole `\[` delimiter (currently, only `[` is colored)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\lstset{
  language=[AlLaTeX]TeX, %
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
  moredelim=*[s][\color{blue}]{[}{]},%
  moredelim=*[s][\color{red}]{\\[}{\\]},%
}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[x=0\]
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\lstset{texcsstyle=*\color{green}}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[x=0\]
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: note that within the listings it is essentially verbatim so `\[` is two tokens `\ ` and `[` but in the setup tokens are read as normal so `\[` is one token (and doesn't match)  as the posted answer shows listings lets you use `\\ ` to refer to the `\ ` token as it appears in the listings body, hence `\\[`

Comment: The update seems to be a separate issue, similar to [lstlisting: color LaTeX commands like \\ or \!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267481/70587). Loading of `tex` aspect partially overrides char table, so you need to "rehook" delimiters char table: `\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{SelectCharTable}{\lst@DefDelims}
\makeatother` after loading `tex` aspect (so after using `\lstset{
  language=[AlLaTeX]TeX}`)

Comment: @jkuczm That does the trick! Could you make this comment an answer in order I can accept it? I'm not sure to understand your explanation neither here nor in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267701/18401 (and I have currently no time to look further into this) but does what you point be considered as a `listing` bug?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé "... does what you point be considered as a listing bug?" Yes, I believe it might be considered a subtle bug in how `tex` aspect interacts with other `listings` aspects.

Comment: @jkuczm Attention of the `listings`' maintainer drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem of interaction of `texcsstyle=*...` option with `moredelim` option, from updated question, seems to be a separate issue, than missing backslash, from original question, solved already by [answer of Schweinebacke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352197/70587).

Issue from update is similar to problem of interaction of `texcsstyle=*...` option with `literate` option, described in my [answer to "lstlisting: color LaTeX commands like `\\` or `\!`" question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267701/70587).

When `tex` aspect is loaded, it adds code, to `SelectCharTable` hook, that can override behavior of backslashes defined using other aspects. To restore proper behavior one can add relevant code to `SelectCharTable` hook after loading `tex` aspect. In case of `moredelim` option relevant code is `\lst@DefDelims` macro.

Full example of "rehooking" delimiters char table is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
  language=[AlLaTeX]TeX, %
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
  texcsstyle=*\color{green},%
  moredelim=*[s][\color{blue}]{[}{]},%
  moredelim=*[s][\color{red}]{\\[}{\\]},%
}

% "Rehook" delimiters char table.
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{SelectCharTable}{\lst@DefDelims}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[x=0\]
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: print screen of PDF]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
  moredelim=*[s][\color{blue}]{[}{]},%
  moredelim=*[s][\color{red}]{\\[}{\\]},%
}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[x=0\]
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need this extra backslash for `{`, `}`, `#`, `%` and `\`.
See note 5 in section 4.1 of the `listings` manual.

Comment: Sigh... I was *sure* I gave a try to this trick :(

Comment: In fact, this trick doesn't work if the optional star of `texcsstyle` is also
used in order to highlight the backslash in front of the control sequence
names. See my edited question (and sorry for the noise).