# lstlisting typesets incorrectly some special characters when used with fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec

This document results in the ellipsis (triple dots) being typeset before the parenthesis. Why is this so? How can I avoid this behavior?

Note that I use the unicode Horizontal Ellipsis U+2026 character, not three dots.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
(…)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/2388

Comment: @Ulrike ok, my question looks like a duplicate. Strange that I didn’t find it. I guess I’ll have a look at minted.