# Listings & unicode characters

Tags: xetex, listings, unicode

I want to write some unicode characters to `lstlisting` environment but they are displayed inline in the output which isn't what I am expecting. How can I make it work like standard characters? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
    └
    └
    └
    \end{lstlisting}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of [xetex - The 'listings' package and UTF-8 - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sorry if you find my answer inappropriate, but after playing around for a while with your code the easiest variant I found is to switch from `lstlisting` package to `minted`.

Why `minted`?

**Pros:**

- Works great with pdflatex, xelatex and so on
- Supports much more languages to highlight, than `lstlisting`
- Sometimes performs highlighting look better
- Has no problems with UTF-8 characters out-of-the-box

**Cons:**

- Requires additional software (though it takes 2-5 minutes to install)
- Needs to edit the compilation command flags (another 30 seconds)

The good news is that *additional software* mentioned above is Python, which is likely to come with your system if you use OS X or any popular Linux distro, and its package Pygments, which can be installed with one line in the shell.

You can head to `minted` [manual](http://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) and check section 2.1, the instructions are very short and informative.

Also you need to check your TeX editor settings and change something like

```
/Library/tex/texbin/xelatex -synctex=1 %.tex
```

adding `-shell-escape` flag, so now it looks something like

```
/Library/tex/texbin/xelatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 %.tex
```

This is to allow XeLaTeX call stuff outside its "sandbox" (in our case to call Python).

After these steps you are ready to use `minted`. No setup will be ever needed again.

---

Now your MWE, adapted for `minted`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{text}
    └
    └
    └
    \end{minted}    
\end{document}
```

Notice the option `{text}` — it is to specify language (in our case plain text).

And the result:

[image]

---

P.S. I have never worked with `minted` before, but trying to solve you problem I spent over 40 minutes playing with `lstlisting` and only 2 minutes installing and getting used to `minted`, so it definitely worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, `minted` looks good but it has one big disadvantage for me. Compilation with many code fragments is now much slower than before, using `lstlisting`.

Comment: Hey, two weeks passed :-) Have you found any solution? If so, you can post your workaround as your own answer and mark it as accepted to help future generations. Otherwise, you can accept my answer, if you find it useful despite longer compilation time.