# Importing code files with unicode using listings

Tags: listings, unicode

I've written a program in python, about 2500 lines in total, that I wish to include segments from into my report. Normally I use `listings` to do that but in this case, the `.py` files include many unicode characters which are necessary for the understanding of the files.

These characters, e.g. ⇒, cause these errors in latex

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\lst@FillFixed@ (U+5B4) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined (inputenc) in inputencoding `utf8'.
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Fists Chapter}
Some text
\lstinputlisting[language=Python, inputencoding=utf8, extendedchars=true]{code.py}
\end{document}
```

*.py file*

```
def Code(self):
    print("Some code with comments"):
    # Comments with unicode characters 
    # β∠ζπ⇒
```

Comment: It's not easy. check for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378600/unicode-characters-in-lstlisting (I have a `literate` set for Spanish language, that's quite easy --- but doing that for a lot of chars is difficult).

Comment: For full Unicode support you should probably be using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. If I remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, switch to `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` and compile with LuaLaTeX the code prints as expected. Oh, and if you are a Python person anyway, you may want to try `minted` instead of `listings`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300719/35864

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25391/35864