# listings package rearranges (Emoji) characters

Tags: xetex, listings, unicode

When I render the following document with xelatex...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\newfontface{\emojifont}{Symbola_hint.ttf}

\begin{document}
\emojifont{The emoji end up in front of the punctuation: \lstinline`<,/+`}
\end{document}
```

I end up with the content of the inline code span looking like `<,/+`—the Emoji are moved across the punctuation, to the start of the span. This doesn't happen (or at least happens differently) with non-punctuation characters.

The same happens in code listing blocks, and since I have to typeset some programs with emoji in them, this is rather disruptive. Any ideas on why this is happening and whether there's a way to work around it?

Using `\texttt` instead of `\lstinline` removes the issue, but I really prefer to keep using `listings`, since it does several things that I need.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396

Comment: That means I have to manually add every Unicode character I want to use in my listings in to cryptic list? That's beyond terrible.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have been it—even with the extra invocations (with appropriate character codes) shown in that answer, the rearranging still happens.

Comment: @Marijn Unless you want a gigantic macro to be executed each time `listings` is processed…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method shown in [The 'listings' package and UTF-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396) works here fine for me too (I had to use another emoji font as I don't have yours installed). I tested both with xelatex and lualatex on a current texlive 2017:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\newfontface{\emojifont}{seguiemj.ttf}
\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
  ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
  ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
  ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
  ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
  ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
  ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
  ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
  %
% ^^^^^1f600^^^^^1f914^^^^^1f3a8%alternative for xelatex, doesn't work in lualatex 
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\emojifont{The emoji end up in front of the punctuation: \lstinline`<,/+`}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that in LuaTeX you have to use six hats, with a padding 0 (it should also work in XeTeX).

Comment: @egreg Yes, thanks David just told me in the chat too, I will correct the example later.

Comment: Thank you, it really does work (not sure what I did wrong when testing). I'm still sad to have to include a hack like this to get basic Unicode support, but I can automate the extraction of characters used so I guess I'll survive.

Comment: As egreg already commented: Do you really expect listings to add support for over 100.000 symbols by default? And even if it would extend the range of supported symbols why on earth should it add emojis?