# How to properly use UTF8 with latexdemo package

Tags: pdftex, input-encodings, listingsutf8

I want to have Umlauts in a [latexdemo](https://ctan.org/pkg/latexdemo) environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{latexdemo}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{\democodefile}
Großschreibung
\end{filecontents*}

\PrintDemo{style=parallel}

\end{document}
```

`pdflatex` compilation error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ├\lst@ECƒ (U+9E9F)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Sure, it compiles fine with `lualatex`.

I tried adding `listingsutf8`, I assume, there is more configuration needed?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{latexdemo}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{\democodefile}
Großschreibung
\end{filecontents*}

\PrintDemo{style=parallel}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are almost there, but you did not read the `lstlistingsutf8` manual, it does nothing on its own. Try adding `\lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin1  }`, and remember this only works for characters representable in latin1

Comment: not all chars will work without problems with lualatex. Try out e.g. `cœur`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396

Comment: @daleif This solves my issue. Could you convert your comment t a full answer. With the additional not of @UlrikeFischer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, but you did not read the `lstlistingsutf8` manual, it does nothing on its own. Add

```
 \lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin1  }
```

and remember this only works for characters representable in latin1