# Devanagari characters in lstlist enviornment

Tags: listings, unicode, listingsutf8

I am using package `listingsutf8` to have a highlighted python code in my tex output. Try this code -

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage{fontspec} % Currently commented as making no change in the output.
%\setmainfont{Sanskrit2003} % Use any Devanagari font here.
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        अ=( "अ","आ","इ","ई","उ","ए","ऐ","ओ","औ")
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Even if you use `listings` result doesn't change. I've tried adding a font which has these characters with package `fontspec`. Still not getting the characters. What should I do?

---

I tried the solution provided by Ulrike Fischer. This is the new code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Yashomudra}
\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
    \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
    ^^^^0905^^^^0906^^^^0907^^^^0908^^^^0909^^^^090a^^^^090b^^^^090c^^^^090d^^^^090e^^^^090f^^^^0911^^^^0912^^^^0913^^^^0914^^^^0915^^^^0916^^^^0917^^^^0918^^^^0919^^^^0920^^^^0921^^^^0922^^^^0923^^^^0924^^^^0925^^^^0926^^^^0927^^^^0928^^^^0929^^^^0930^^^^0931^^^^0932^^^^0933^^^^0934^^^^0935^^^^0936^^^^0937^^^^0938^^^^0939^^^^091a^^^^091b^^^^091c^^^^091d^^^^091e^^^^091f^^^^092a^^^^092b^^^^092c^^^^092d^^^^092e^^^^092f^^^^093e^^^^093f^^^^0940^^^^0941^^^^0942^^^^0943^^^^0944^^^^0945^^^^0946^^^^0947^^^^0948^^^^0949^^^^094b^^^^094d^^^^094c^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[extendedchars=true]
        हा देवनागरी लिपीतील मजकूर आहे
        परंतु ह्यात स्वरांशचिन्हे योग्यरूपात दिसत नाहीत.
    \end{lstlisting}
    हा देवनागरी लिपीतील मजकूर आहे\\
    ह्यात स्वरांशचिन्हे योग्यरूपात दिसत आहेत.
\end{document}
```

Now my output looks like this -

[image: 1]

How to solve this?

Comment: listingsutf8 is unsuitable for the unicode engines. See here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396

Comment: I just saw the code that you have provided there, but I want this for a different script. Can you explain what that code means (I mean the stuff inside makeatletter and makeatother) so that I can replace it with the characters that I want?

Comment: Also what if I just want to use listings and also these characters to be processed? Can it be done? Because I must use Xe or Lua. There are other reasons for it.

Comment: simply add your numbers. E.g. औ is U+0914, so you should add `^^^^0914` behind the `^^^^0152`.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listings handles the input one by one. It is doesn't work well with scripts like your which do lots of ligatures. You can improve the output with `columns=fullflexible` but this isn't perfect either. The best result can be get with minted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\setmonofont[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
    \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
    ^^^^0905^^^^0906^^^^0907^^^^0908^^^^0909^^^^090a^^^^090b^^^^090c^^^^090d^^^^090e^^^^090f^^^^0911^^^^0912^^^^0913^^^^0914^^^^0915^^^^0916^^^^0917^^^^0918^^^^0919^^^^0920^^^^0921^^^^0922^^^^0923^^^^0924^^^^0925^^^^0926^^^^0927^^^^0928^^^^0929^^^^0930^^^^0931^^^^0932^^^^0933^^^^0934^^^^0935^^^^0936^^^^0937^^^^0938^^^^0939^^^^091a^^^^091b^^^^091c^^^^091d^^^^091e^^^^091f^^^^092a^^^^092b^^^^092c^^^^092d^^^^092e^^^^092f^^^^093e^^^^093f^^^^0940^^^^0941^^^^0942^^^^0943^^^^0944^^^^0945^^^^0946^^^^0947^^^^0948^^^^0949^^^^094b^^^^094d^^^^094c^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[extendedchars=true,columns=fullflexible]
        हा देवनागरी लिपीतील मजकूर आहे
        परंतु ह्यात स्वरांशचिन्हे योग्यरूपात दिसत नाहीत.
\end{lstlisting}


\begin{minted}{latex}
        हा देवनागरी लिपीतील मजकूर आहे
        परंतु ह्यात स्वरांशचिन्हे योग्यरूपात दिसत नाहीत.
\end{minted}

    हा देवनागरी लिपीतील मजकूर आहे\\
    ह्यात स्वरांशचिन्हे योग्यरूपात दिसत आहेत.
\end{document}
```

### Output of `xelatex --shell-escape file`

[image]