# Including Unicode in listings with pdflatex/luatex/xelatex

Tags: unicode

Python and Julia support unicode which makes it easy to write code which looks like math, i.e. (f = σ-> κ* σ ).  Now, I'm trying to copy over some of this code into notes, with the listings package.  But pdflatex doesn't want to compile it.  I tried lualatex, and then I have no errors, but the symbols don't show up.  Just to reiterate, I am **not** trying to include the unicode in a math environment.

Example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
F = lambda x: α * x + β 
\end{lstlisting}
```

Compiles, but α and β appear as blank, in the tex:[image]

Comment: As always on the site you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full (but minimal) self contained example that others can test as is.

Comment: That being said listings does not support random 2byte chars so I would not be surprised that `(f = σ-> κ* σ )` does not work in listings. There are some workarounds but they mostly involve specifying mappings for the needed non ascii chars.

Comment: The symbols will show up with luatex if you use a suitable font that has the characters. for pdflatex it's a bit harder but a start would be `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

f = σ-> κ* σ )


\end{document}
` (but note the f)  If you want help with an error show a small but complete document and teh exact error that you get.

Comment: See here about how to add arbitrary symbols to listings https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396 (you still need a suitable font for the symbols).

Comment: Fischer's suggested link doesn't work for the greek characters I want (but does, otherwise, work).