# listings changes the order of characters in a line of code

Tags: xetex, listings

This is my minimum example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
loads = {'-g·M·e·(Σsines),'; 'wind-like·half-sine,'};
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%% End:
```

and here it is what I get, using XeLaTeX on Debian Sid

[image]

Please notice the position of "Σ" with respect to "(" in the source and in the
figure.

My question is, what is going on?

Comment: you must add such chars to the process list first, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer