# Not all UTF8 symbols work in lstlistings

Tags: listings, unicode, listingsutf8

I am on Linux and I have this document that I compile using `xelatex main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{code_linenumbers_b}{RGB}{215,215,215}
    \definecolor{code_linenumbers}{RGB}{255,255,255}
    \definecolor{code_background}{RGB}{250,250,250}
    \definecolor{code_comments}{RGB}{185,185,185}
    \definecolor{code_borders}{RGB}{86,211,239}

\usepackage{mathspec}
    \setallmonofonts[
        %Path=.,
        Extension=.ttf,
        Scale=0.8,
        UprightFont=*--regular,
        BoldFont=*--bold,
        ItalicFont=*--italic
    ]{liberation-mono}

\usepackage{listings}
    %Global
    \lstset{
        %frame
        frame=l,
        captionpos=b,
        numbersep=3.5mm,
        xleftmargin=0.35cm,
        xrightmargin=0cm,
        framesep=0mm,
        framexleftmargin=2.5mm,
        framerule=0.5mm,
        %colors
        backgroundcolor=\color{code_background},
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
        numberstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries\color{code_linenumbers},
        fillcolor=\color{code_linenumbers_b},
        commentstyle=\color{code_comments},
        keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
        rulecolor=\color{code_borders},
        %code format
        showspaces=false,
        breaklines=true,
        breakatwhitespace=true,
        tabsize=3,
        columns=flexible
    }

\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting[
        language=C,
        caption=\lstinline{main.c},
        label=r001,
        numbers=left,
        xleftmargin=1.15cm,
        framesep=8mm
    ]{main.c}

\end{document}
```

and my `main.c` file looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    //            ir
    //            ↓
    //        012345678
    //      0     *
    //      1    ***
    //      2   *****
    //      3  *******
    // ir → 4 *********

    return 0;
}
```

But after compiling *(with no errors or warnings)* I get the resulting `main.pdf` where arrows `↓` (`U+2193`) & `→` (`U+2192`) are not properly positioned:

[image]

All the `*.ttf` fonts are inside the same folder than the `main.tex` and `main.c`.

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:mwe$ ls -l
total 468
-rw-r--r-- 1 ziga ziga 120308 May 21 17:30 liberation-mono--bold-italic.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 ziga ziga 107620 May 21 17:30 liberation-mono--bold.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 ziga ziga 126308 May 21 17:30 liberation-mono--italic.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 ziga ziga 110204 May 21 17:29 liberation-mono--regular.ttf
-rw-r--r-- 1 ziga ziga    229 May 21 18:45 main.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 ziga ziga   1479 May 21 18:50 main.tex
```

and they do have a *glyphs* for arrows `↓` (`U+2193`) & `→` (`U+2192`) which I double checked by opening all the `*.ttf` files with [Fontforge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/):

[image]

[image]

`xelatex` is an UTF-8 engine and should support UTF-8 encoded multibyte characters... So why don't they render properly?

Comment: You should use `keepspaces` option in `\lstset`.

Comment: Thank you! This solved half of my problem. Now arrows are aligned properly but are still not the same color as the rest of the comments. Any Idea on how to solve this as well?

Answer (score 1):

I use this method: [The 'listings' package and UTF-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8)

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse 
 \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^^^2192^^^^2193^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother
\lstset{
   basicstyle=\ttfamily,
   keepspaces,
   commentstyle=\color{gray},
   extendedchars
}
\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting[language=C]{main.c}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a fix to make this work for all utf8 characters? I don't want to write this all the time...

Comment: No. Only `U+2193` and `U+2192` work in this code.

Comment: See the link in the answer.

Comment: I checked the link and tried the last answer there which is to use `texcl=true` inside `\lstset{}`. This colored my comments properly, but removed any kind of indentation at the beginning of the line. So if I use this all the comments are mooved completely to the left.

Comment: The first answer is the relevant.

Comment: Yes. But it is painful to define `^^^^2192`... for each UTF-8 character... Don't you think?