# Some characters have strange behaviour in listings with lualatex

Tags: listings, luatex, unicode

The following MCE points out that some characters (for instance `€`, `→` or `←`) have strange behavior (shifted on the left) in listings with `lualatex` (up to date TeX Live 2020). Do you know why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item §Foo§
\item «Foo«
\item €Foo€
\item →Foo→
\item ←Foo←
\end{enumerate}

\begin{lstlisting}
1. §Foo§
2. «Foo«
3. €Foo€
4. →Foo→
5. ←Foo←
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/2388

Comment: Not a big surprise, `listings` doesn't support UTF-8.  You can try saving your listing in an external file and load it using [`listingsutf8`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listingsutf8) package.

Comment: @HenriMenke AFAIK, `listings` doesn't support UTF-8 with `pdftex` engine; here I consider the `luatex` engine. And my MCE shows that `listings`, when used with `luatex` engine, supports at least some Unicode characters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't find the question you link since I was searching with 'lualatex". So I think it is worth not considering my question as duplicate. BTW, do you think it is worth asking the `listings` maintainer to add (a limited part of) chars with Unicode positions above 256 to the processing list of `listings`?

Comment: it is always easier to find a question when you know it is there ;-). I have linked to this quite often. It would be worth to ask for the € as it is also in T1. Beside this it could be worth to ask for a proper "add range of chars"-inferface (but perhaps there is already one, my answer is from 2011 and I didn't checked if is can be done easier now).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Attention of `listings`' maintainer drawn.