# How to correctly display 〈 and 〉 in a listing's listing?

Tags: luatex, listings, unicode

This question is a continuation of [The 'listings' package and UTF-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25391/18401). I'm trying to display the characters [〈](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2329) and [〉](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+232A) in a listing (from the `listings` package). Thanks to [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/18401), I added them to the processing list of `listings` first and use `extendedchars=true`, using their Unicode positions (if I'm right, `2329` and `232A`).

As shown by the following MCE, these characters are displayed but badly positioned.

How to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,extendedchars=true,frame=single}

\DeclareTextSymbol{\textlangle}\UnicodeEncodingName{"2329}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textrangle}\UnicodeEncodingName{"232A}

\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
  ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
  ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
  ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
  ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
  ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
  ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
  ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
  ^^^^20ac^^^^0153^^^^0152% nouveau pour xetex
  ^^^^2329%  Left-Pointing Angle Bracket
  ^^^^232a% Right-Pointing Angle Bracket
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\ttfamily{}
⟨foo⟩
\begin{lstlisting}
⟨foo⟩
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wrong numbers, the symbols are `^^^^27e8` and   `^^^^27e9`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, thanks! But where are these numbers coming from?

Comment: I can see the numbers in my editor, or by using an application called BabelPad. You could also use https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

Comment: In `vim`, install https://github.com/tpope/vim-characterize and the  `ga` when over the character...