# Non-ASCII escape characters

Tags: xetex, listings, input-encodings, characters

I'm using all ASCII characters in my code blocks, so I need to reach for non-ASCII ones for the escape characters. I expected Xetex to deal with this just fine; alas, it doesn't seem to be the case.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{escapeinside=〈〉}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
foo bar baz〈\textit{hello}〉
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

When typeset by running `latexmk -xelatex foo.tex`, this results in a code listing that contains "\textit{hello}" instead of "*hello*".

How do I use non-ASCII escape characters within `lstlisting`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must enable the parsing:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter 
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
  ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
  ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
  ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
  ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
  ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
  ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
  ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
  ^^^^3008^^^^3009% angle chars for xelatex
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother

\lstset{escapeinside=〈〉}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
foo bar baz〈\textit{hello}〉
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

See also [The 'listings' package and UTF-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8/25396#25396)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "eating a space" -- if I put a space between `baz` and `〈\textit{hello}〉`, then there is a space between "baz" and "_hello_".

Comment: not in my screenshot, but I'm a bit in a hurry so I can't check now if it is really missing or is I removed by accident.

Comment: your examples doesn't have a space in the source code either. And neither does my original code.

Comment: ah, it is the font, the left angle has a rather wide side bearing which looks like a space ;-)