# Type ⟨ and ⟩ inside a \lstinline command

Tags: xetex, fontspec, newunicodechar

I want to type the angle bracket inside a `listings` inline code.

```
like ⟨this⟩
```

I set up `listings` to be (globally) typed in the Latin Modern Mono.

With the following

```tex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec,hyperref,listings}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
breaklines=true,
language=TeX,
extendedchars=true
}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^^^27e8% Left-Pointing Angle Bracket
  ^^^^27e9% Right-Pointing Angle Bracket}
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
The command is \lstinline$\newfontfamily⟨cmd⟩{font}{options}$.
\end{document}
```

I get this output:

[image]

Even after adding the `makeatletter`-`makeatlatter` code suggested in the comments, the brackets are not displayed in the output.

What is it that I am missing here?

Comment: 1. According to the font catalog https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html the name should be "Latin Modern Mono". 2. `listings` is known not to play well with "extended" characters. There's a whole section about it in the documentation, including some suggestions (such as "escape to LaTeX"). 3. With typewriter font, why not just use `<` and `>`?

Comment: the \ttfamily doesn't have the glyphs, only 〈〉.  To use such chars in the input of listings you must add them to the processing list, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited the original question. I still don't succeed getting it right.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Besides, Could you give some explanation about where this code block (the one beginning with `\lst@InputCatcodes  \def\lst@DefEC{%`) comes from?

Comment: the code is from the sty. I looked that up some years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different brackets in unicode and the typewriter font has only glyphs for one pair (U+2329, U+232A) (yes there are different even if they look quite similar depending on the font). You can use literate to map the unknown glyphs to the known one.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
breaklines=true,
language=TeX,
extendedchars=true
}


\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^^^27e8% Mathematical Left-Pointing Angle Bracket
  ^^^^27e9% Mathematical Right-Pointing Angle Bracket}
  ^^^^2329% Left-Pointing Angle Bracket
  ^^^^232a% Right-Pointing Angle Bracket}
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes

\lstset{literate={⟨}{〈}1{⟩}{〉}1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The command is \lstinline$\newfontfamily⟨cmd⟩{font}{options}$. %27e8

The command is \lstinline$\newfontfamily〈cmd〉{font}{options}$. %2329

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I still [can't get them typed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3qaY.png). I use XeLaTeX with TeXworks 0.6.6 on Mac 12.1 with texlive 2021.

Comment: Did you copy & pasted & tried my example as it is?

Comment: Yes. Complete copy and paste.

Comment: Then put the tex file of the example, the log and the pdf in a zip somewhere for download.

Comment: [zip](https://mega.nz/file/T6JxBIBL#-eqdMjAZa3F72hWab2OpXnUhyIkuLgKJZClz-37llxM). Thanks a lot for the time you put into it.

Looking at it now I see that I get the messages `Missing character: There is no 〈 (U+3008) in font [lmmono10-regular]` for each bra and ket.

Comment: well yes your second pair is 3008 and 3009 and not 2329/232A. Your mac seems to have normalized them at the copy&paste (they are equivalent unicode code points).  Exchange the numbers.

Comment: Hmm I don't understand. The problem is in the characters I "typed" into the tex file? What do you mean "exchange the numbers"?

Comment: The mac likes to normalize things and to change input.   Use 3008 instead of 2329.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133629/discussion-between-tush-and-ulrike-fischer).