# Spaces missing in Greek text in listings

Tags: spacing, xetex, listings, greek

I have the following `xelatex` document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\setromanfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}
\setmainfont{FreeSans}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
   basicstyle=\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont\ttfamily
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

  Αρχικοποίηση του SESSION ώστε να 
  
  Initializing of the SESSION so 

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=protected.php,frame=tlrb]{Name}
<?php
  session_start(); # Αρχικοποίηση του SESSION ώστε να 
  session_start(); # Initializing of the SESSION so  

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But the problem is that the Greek text in the code listing appears with the spaces missing. The text outside the code listing appears with correct spacing:

How can I fix the text in the listing so the spaces appear normally?

[image]

Comment: unrelated to the question, but `\scriptsize\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont` ? `\scriptsize` is doing nothing there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That seems to be correct. In fact, the entire `\lstset` block can be removed and the problem still exists, but when creating the minimal example I left the font formatting because the solution could possibly depend on that.

Comment: never use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with xetex (it just gives a warning saying not to use it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, for instance, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/4427

You need to add the Greek block U+0370–U+03FF. Possibly also Greek Extended U+1F00–U+1FFF.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{listings}

\setmainfont{FreeSans}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
\setmonofont{FreeMono}

\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\lstset{
   basicstyle=\fontsize{11}{13}\ttfamily,
   extendedchars=true,
}

\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
  ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
  ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
  ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
  ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
  ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
  ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
  ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
  % add Greek
  ^^^^0370^^^^0371^^^^0372^^^^0373^^^^0374^^^^0375^^^^0376^^^^0377%
  ^^^^0378^^^^0379^^^^037a^^^^037b^^^^037c^^^^037d^^^^037e^^^^037f%
  ^^^^0380^^^^0381^^^^0382^^^^0383^^^^0384^^^^0385^^^^0386^^^^0387%
  ^^^^0388^^^^0389^^^^038a^^^^038b^^^^038c^^^^038d^^^^038e^^^^038f%
  ^^^^0390^^^^0391^^^^0392^^^^0393^^^^0394^^^^0395^^^^0396^^^^0397%
  ^^^^0398^^^^0399^^^^039a^^^^039b^^^^039c^^^^039d^^^^039e^^^^039f%
  ^^^^03a0^^^^03a1^^^^03a2^^^^03a3^^^^03a4^^^^03a5^^^^03a6^^^^03a7%
  ^^^^03a8^^^^03a9^^^^03aa^^^^03ab^^^^03ac^^^^03ad^^^^03ae^^^^03af%
  ^^^^03b0^^^^03b1^^^^03b2^^^^03b3^^^^03b4^^^^03b5^^^^03b6^^^^03b7%
  ^^^^03b8^^^^03b9^^^^03ba^^^^03bb^^^^03bc^^^^03bd^^^^03be^^^^03bf%
  ^^^^03c0^^^^03c1^^^^03c2^^^^03c3^^^^03c4^^^^03c5^^^^03c6^^^^03c7%
  ^^^^03c8^^^^03c9^^^^03ca^^^^03cb^^^^03cc^^^^03cd^^^^03ce^^^^03cf%
  ^^^^03d0^^^^03d1^^^^03d2^^^^03d3^^^^03d4^^^^03d5^^^^03d6^^^^03d7%
  ^^^^03d8^^^^03d9^^^^03da^^^^03db^^^^03dc^^^^03dd^^^^03de^^^^03df%
  ^^^^03e0^^^^03e1^^^^03e2^^^^03e3^^^^03e4^^^^03e5^^^^03e6^^^^03e7%
  ^^^^03e8^^^^03e9^^^^03ea^^^^03eb^^^^03ec^^^^03ed^^^^03ee^^^^03ef%
  ^^^^03f0^^^^03f1^^^^03f2^^^^03f3^^^^03f4^^^^03f5^^^^03f6^^^^03f7%
  ^^^^03f8^^^^03f9^^^^03fa^^^^03fb^^^^03fc^^^^03fd^^^^03fe^^^^03ff%
  % the end
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother


\begin{document}

  Αρχικοποίηση του SESSION ώστε να 
  
  Initializing of the SESSION so 

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=protected.php,frame=tlrb]{Name}
<?php
  session_start(); # Αρχικοποίηση του SESSION ώστε να 
  session_start(); # Initializing of the SESSION so  

\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I used `geometry` in order to avoid overfull lines.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. So the problem is that the listing environment doesn't recognize the Greek letters as valid unicode codepoints, so we need to define them manually?

Comment: @user000001 That's precisely the problem.