# Greek letter inside a listings environment

Tags: listings, greek, fira-sans

I have some Greek letters in my Python script that I'd like to typeset with a listings environment. I use the FiraCode font that seems to support Greek letters. But the Greek letters sometimes do not appear where they should. My engine is `luatex`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{FiraCode}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle = \ttfamily, language = Python}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  def test(λ):
    return λ
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: lambda is before braces]

Is there a fix?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the link. It solves the issue. Should I close the question as duplicate or do you want to answer it?