# How to insert code with accents with listings?

Tags: listings, accents

I'm trying to insert source code in LaTeX with using `listings`, but my code has accents and pdflatex gives me this error:

```
Unicode char \u8:�\expandafter not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

This is a code the reproduces the error.

### example.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[language=C++]{code.cpp}

\end{document}
```

### code.cpp

```
// Código con una tilde
```

What can I do to generate the PDF correctly?

Comment: The OP's question was about `lstinputlisting`. **For environment e.g. `\begin{lstlisting}` see [unicode - Having problems with listings and UTF-8. Can it be fixed? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed?noredirect=1&lq=1)**.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can load the package `listingsutf8` and then set the encoding using `\lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin1}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin1}
\lstinputlisting[language=C++]{code.cpp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With the second method the _ó_ is not in its right place, but the first method works perfectly!.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice the slight misalignment. I've removed the second method.

Comment: the accpeted solution doesn´t work for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[french]{babel}` and `\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]`. Although I'm not getting compilation errors, the french characters aren't displayed properly.

Answer (score 25):

The accepted solution didn't work for me, so here is mine:

```
\usepackage{listings} % ordinary listings package
```

and then configure letter mappings - these mappings are for the Czech languaguge but you can configure your own

```
\lstset{
     literate=%
         {á}{{\'a}}1
         {í}{{\'i}}1
         {é}{{\'e}}1
         {ý}{{\'y}}1
         {ú}{{\'u}}1
         {ó}{{\'o}}1
         {ě}{{\v{e}}}1
         {š}{{\v{s}}}1
         {č}{{\v{c}}}1
         {ř}{{\v{r}}}1
         {ž}{{\v{z}}}1
         {ď}{{\v{d}}}1
         {ť}{{\v{t}}}1
         {ň}{{\v{n}}}1                
         {ů}{{\r{u}}}1
         {Á}{{\'A}}1
         {Í}{{\'I}}1
         {É}{{\'E}}1
         {Ý}{{\'Y}}1
         {Ú}{{\'U}}1
         {Ó}{{\'O}}1
         {Ě}{{\v{E}}}1
         {Š}{{\v{S}}}1
         {Č}{{\v{C}}}1
         {Ř}{{\v{R}}}1
         {Ž}{{\v{Z}}}1
         {Ď}{{\v{D}}}1
         {Ť}{{\v{T}}}1
         {Ň}{{\v{N}}}1                
         {Ů}{{\r{U}}}1    
}
```

Comment: Thnak you, I was in your case. The accepted solution doesn´t works for me, and your solutions has solved my problem in spanish.

Comment: Better solution than the accepted one. Very useful for me for french comments in the code.

Comment: Yes, it worked for well nicely in French. Why are there numbers 1 at the end of each line?

Answer (score 12):

In Brazilian portuguese, this solution worked for me

```
\usepackage{listings} % for including code

\lstset{
language=R,   % R code
literate=
{á}{{\'a}}1
{à}{{\`a}}1
{ã}{{\~a}}1
{é}{{\'e}}1
{ê}{{\^e}}1
{í}{{\'i}}1
{ó}{{\'o}}1
{õ}{{\~o}}1
{ú}{{\'u}}1
{ü}{{\"u}}1
{ç}{{\c{c}}}1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hungarian version based on [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85947/104712):

```
\lstset{ literate={á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{{\'\i}}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ő}{{\H o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1 {ű}{{\H u}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1 }
```

LaTex magyar ékezetes karakterek.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked here, just this way:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=bash,   %% PHP, C, Java, etc... bash is the standard
    extendedchars=true,
    inputencoding=latin1
}
```

Comment: This last solution does not work if your source code is in utf-8 and you replace latin1 by utf8 ;-(

Answer (score 3):

Set for Polish language:

```
\lstset{
literate=%
{ą}{{\k{a}}}1
{Ą}{{\k{A}}}1
{ć}{{\'c}}1
{Ć}{{\'{C}}}1
{ę}{{\k{e}}}1
{Ę}{{\k{E}}}1
{ł}{{\l{}}}1
{Ł}{{\L{}}}1
{ń}{{\'n}}1
{Ń}{{\'N}}1
{ó}{{\'o}}1
{Ó}{{\'O}}1
{ś}{{\'s}}1
{Ś}{{\'S}}1
{ż}{{\.z}}1
{Ż}{{\.Z}}1
{ź}{{\'z}}1
{Ź}{{\'Z}}1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set for the Greek language:

```
literate=
{α}{{\textalpha}}1
{β}{{\textbeta}}1
{γ}{{\textgamma}}1
{δ}{{\textdelta}}1
{ε}{{\textepsilon}}1
{ζ}{{\textzeta}}1
{η}{{\texteta}}1
{θ}{{\texttheta}}1
{ι}{{\textiota}}1
{κ}{{\textkappa}}1
{λ}{{\textlambda}}1
{μ}{{\textmu}}1
{ν}{{\textnu}}1
{ξ}{{\textxi}}1
{ο}{{\textomikron}}1
{π}{{\textpi}}1
{ρ}{{\textrho}}1
{σ}{{\textsigma}}1
{τ}{{\texttau}}1
{υ}{{\textupsilon}}1
{φ}{{\textphi}}1
{χ}{{\textchi}}1
{ψ}{{\textpsi}}1
{ω}{{\textomega}}1
{Α}{{\textAlpha}}1
{Β}{{\textBeta}}1
{Γ}{{\textGamma}}1
{Δ}{{\textDelta}}1
{Ε}{{\textEpsilon}}1
{Ζ}{{\textZeta}}1
{Η}{{\textEta}}1
{Θ}{{\textTheta}}1
{Ι}{{\textIota}}1
{Κ}{{\textKappa}}1
{Λ}{{\textLambda}}1
{Μ}{{\textMu}}1
{Ν}{{\textNu}}1
{Ξ}{{\textXi}}1
{Ο}{{\textOmikron}}1
{Π}{{\textPi}}1
{Ρ}{{\textRho}}1
{Σ}{{\textSigma}}1
{Τ}{{\textTau}}1
{Υ}{{\textUpsilon}}1
{Φ}{{\textPhi}}1
{Χ}{{\textChi}}1
{Ψ}{{\textPsi}}1
{Ω}{{\textOmega}}1
{ς}{{\textvarsigma}}1
{φ}{{\straightphi}}1
{θ}{{\scripttheta}}1
{ε}{{\epsilon}}1
{ά}{{\'\textalpha}}1
{έ}{{\'\textepsilon}}1
{ί}{{\'\textiota}}1
{ή}{{\'\texteta}}1
{ό}{{\'\textomikron}}1
{ύ}{{\'\textupsilon}}1
{ώ}{{\'\textomega}}1
```

Answer (score 1):

Set for French language :

```
\lstset{literate=%
{é}{{\'e}}{1}%
{è}{{\`e}}{1}%
{à}{{\`a}}{1}%
{ç}{{\c{c}}}{1}%
{œ}{{\oe}}{1}%
{ù}{{\`u}}{1}%
{É}{{\'E}}{1}%
{È}{{\`E}}{1}%
{À}{{\`A}}{1}%
{Ç}{{\c{C}}}{1}%
{Œ}{{\OE}}{1}%
{Ê}{{\^E}}{1}%
{ê}{{\^e}}{1}%
{î}{{\^i}}{1}%
{ô}{{\^o}}{1}%
{û}{{\^u}}{1}%
{ä}{{\"{a}}}1
{ë}{{\"{e}}}1
{ï}{{\"{i}}}1
{ö}{{\"{o}}}1
{ü}{{\"{u}}}1
{û}{{\^{u}}}1
{â}{{\^{a}}}1
{Â}{{\^{A}}}1
{Î}{{\^{I}}}1
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Notice that the question you answered to was very old. In this day and age, that sort of workaround is no longer necessary. I've been using plain `listings` with regional characters (including French) for years without any need to any configuration. So unless you're stuck on a very old system, using those workarounds should be avoided.

Comment: On overleaf I'm still getting this issue @Miyase

Comment: @Butanium Then you probably have a problem elsewhere in your preamble. I have my students use Overleaf and most of them have code typeset with listings, and the workaround you mention has never been necessary. You should make a pass over your packages and check with CTAN if some of them were deprecated.

Comment: Maybe, I'm using a ieee template so I a lot of packages are included by default