# What is bad in these lines with listings?

Tags: listings

How is bad in the line 28 (AppendTo....)?

LATEX tell me that"missing $"

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
%\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\input{listings-spa.tex}
\lstset{language=Mathematica}
\lstset{basicstyle={\sffamily\footnotesize},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos={t},
  frame={lines},
  rulecolor=\color{black},
  framerule=0.5pt,
  columns=flexible,
  tabsize=2
}

\begin{document}
%\lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin1}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Mathematica,caption={Example code}]
  Do[Print["número=number -> ",i],{i,1,10}];

    AppendTo[bigstat, Last[x]](*    Añadimos la propuesta de solución del algoritmo Codicioso a la lista bistat donde almacenamos todas lassolcuiones propuestas en cada ejecución del mismo. *)    , {p, 1, simulaciones}  (\* Numero de simulaciones \*)
    ];

   Which[opneigh == 1, bigstatbestn2 = bigstat, opneigh == 2,
    bigstatbestn6 = bigstat];(* Almacenamos en bigstatn2,6 o t,
   TODOS los puntos que el algoritmo codicioso da como propuessta de \
solución en cada una de las simulaciones hechas
    La opción=1 indica que consideramos vecindarios de 2 vecinos;
   opción=2 vecindario de 6 vecinos; opcion=3,
   vecindarios de todos los vecinos *)
   Clear[bigstat](*
   Borramos bigstat dado que ya lo tenemos almacenado en la \
correspondiente lista para el analisis finales despues *)
   , {opneigh, 1, 2}
   ] ; (* 1.- con 2 vecinos    2.-con6 vecinos    *)

 Button[" Generar Simulacion", astart = ! astart],
 Style["Versión 1.35b", Darker@Blue, 12],
 Style["Mika Ike . m@gmail.com)", Blue,
  TextAlignment -> Right, 11]
 , ControlPlacement -> Right, Initialization -> (astart = True),
 TrackedSymbols :> {astart}]

  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

listing-spa is to solve the problem af characters á, í, ñ, ...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mip8tkayotqpoj/listings-spa.tex from Tomas message [How to insert code with accents with listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/how-to-insert-code-with-accents-with-listings)

Comment: Is this not basically the same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185898/how-to-improve-compile-this-particular-source-code-in-spanish-using-listings, also by you?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, it´s similar, but I´m deleting the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-8 is not supported by `listings`. Package `listingsutf8` helps, but the code need to be stored in a file, e.g. `example-mathematica.m`:

```
  Do[Print["número=number -> ",i],{i,1,10}];

    AppendTo[bigstat, Last[x]](*    Añadimos la propuesta de solución del algoritmo Codicioso a la lista bistat donde almacenamos todas lassolcuiones propuestas en cada ejecución del mismo. *)    , {p, 1, simulaciones}  (\* Numero de simulaciones \*)
    ];

   Which[opneigh == 1, bigstatbestn2 = bigstat, opneigh == 2,
    bigstatbestn6 = bigstat];(* Almacenamos en bigstatn2,6 o t,
   TODOS los puntos que el algoritmo codicioso da como propuessta de \
solución en cada una de las simulaciones hechas
    La opción=1 indica que consideramos vecindarios de 2 vecinos;
   opción=2 vecindario de 6 vecinos; opcion=3,
   vecindarios de todos los vecinos *)
   Clear[bigstat](*
   Borramos bigstat dado que ya lo tenemos almacenado en la \
correspondiente lista para el analisis finales despues *)
   , {opneigh, 1, 2}
   ] ; (* 1.- con 2 vecinos    2.-con6 vecinos    *)

 Button[" Generar Simulacion", astart = ! astart],
 Style["Versión 1.35b", Darker@Blue, 12],
 Style["Mika Ike . m@gmail.com)", Blue,
  TextAlignment -> Right, 11]
 , ControlPlacement -> Right, Initialization -> (astart = True),
 TrackedSymbols :> {astart}]
```

The the TeX file looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\lstset{basicstyle={\sffamily\footnotesize},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos={t},
  frame={lines},
  rulecolor=\color{black},
  framerule=0.5pt,
  columns=flexible,
  tabsize=2,
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[
  language=Mathematica,
  caption={Example code},
  inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
]{example-mathematica.m}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- Two options do not make much sense for package `inputenc`. You cannot have two input encodings at the same time. An input encoding can be switched later by macro `\inputencoding{<encoding option>}`.

Comment: When I copy (Ctrl+C) from Mathematica, automatically appears \ at the end of long line comments. Is possible to delete it. I know that the important was solved! Thank you.

Comment: @MikaIke: I would clean up the source code in the first place: indenting, line length, spaces (consistent, after comma, ...). In the current form the code is quite unreadable. If the line length is limited without long lines, then the backslash problem would also be solved.