# How to use showexpl with tufte-handout

Tags: tufte, showexpl

I'm working on a document using the `tufte-handout` class in which I need to include some examples of `LaTeX` code for which I try to work with the package `showexpl` in the way it appears in my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}    
\usepackage{showexpl}

 \lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]Tex}
 \lstset{%
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
     commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small,
     showspaces=false,
     showstringspaces=false,
     breaklines=true,
     breakautoindent=true,
     captionpos=t
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}  
\begin{itemize}
\item Introducción a \LaTeX
\item Texto con \LaTeX
\begin{itemize}
\item Reglas básicas
\item Entornos de texto
\begin{itemize}
\item Incisos, citaciones y poemas
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{quote}
\item \textsf{quotation}
\item \textsf{verse}
\end{itemize}
\item Listas
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{itemize}
\item \textsf{enumerate}
\item \textsf{description}
\end{itemize}
\item Texto alineado horizontalmente
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{flushleft}
\item \textsf{center}
\item \textsf{flushright}
\end{itemize}
\item Texto mecanografiado
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{verbatim}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

However, something goes wrong, and seems to be unable to compile. I don't know if it has to see the width of the typographic case in this class or if it's because it can't works in two columns.

I receive the following error message:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:\expandafter not set up for use with LaTeX.
Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
```

It only happens wihen I try to introduce a `LTXexampe`environment. Otherwise the compilation runs well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not the document class, but the accented letters from Spanish (in this particular case, "ó" and "á"). The known workarounds for listings: using literate or even escaping the accented characters to LaTeX (suugested, for example, in [How to insert code with accents with listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30512/3954)) won't work for `showexpl` since non-ascii characters get lost when the temporary file internally used is written.

I'd like to suggest you the powerful [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package and its nice interaction with `listings`; here's a little example (adjust the settings according to your needs; in particular, you need to add support for accented uppercase vowels, the crema and the eñe):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}    
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

 \lstset{%
     language=[LaTeX]TeX,
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
     commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small,
     showspaces=false,
     showstringspaces=false,
     breaklines=true,
     breakautoindent=true,
     captionpos=t,
     literate=%
       {á}{{\'a}}1 
       {é}{{\'e}}1 
       {í}{{\'i}}1 
       {ó}{{\'o}}1 
       {ú}{{\'u}}1 
}

\tcbset{
  example/.style 2 args={
    colframe=red!50!black, 
    colback=red!50!black!5,
    fonttitle=\small\sffamily\bfseries, 
    fontupper=\small,   
    fontlower=\small,
    text outside listing,
    title={Ejemplo~\thetcbcounter: #1},label={#2}},
}
\newtcblisting[auto counter]{micodigo}[3][]{example={#2}{#3},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{micodigo}{ejemplo de listas}{eje:lista}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introducción a \LaTeX
\item Texto con \LaTeX
\begin{itemize}
\item Reglas básicas
\item Entornos de texto
\begin{itemize}
\item Incisos, citaciones y poemas
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{quote}
\item \textsf{quotation}
\item \textsf{verse}
\end{itemize}
\item Listas
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{itemize}
\item \textsf{enumerate}
\item \textsf{description}
\end{itemize}
\item Texto alineado horizontalmente
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{flushleft}
\item \textsf{center}
\item \textsf{flushright}
\end{itemize}
\item Texto mecanografiado
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{verbatim}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{micodigo}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

As **Ignasi** suggested in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252222/how-to-use-showexpl-with-tufte-handout/252236?noredirect=1#comment601704_252236), you can avoid the use of `literate` by using the `listingsutf8` package. In this case, you load `tcolorbox` as follows:

```
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}
\tcbset{listing utf8=latin1}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}    
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}
\tcbset{listing utf8=latin1}

 \lstset{%
     language=[LaTeX]TeX,
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
     commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small,
     showspaces=false,
     showstringspaces=false,
     breaklines=true,
     breakautoindent=true,
     captionpos=t,
}

\tcbset{
  example/.style 2 args={
    colframe=red!50!black, 
    colback=red!50!black!5,
    fonttitle=\small\sffamily\bfseries, 
    fontupper=\small,   
    fontlower=\small,
    text outside listing,
    title={Ejemplo~\thetcbcounter: #1},label={#2}},
}
\newtcblisting[auto counter]{micodigo}[3][]{example={#2}{#3},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{micodigo}{ejemplo de listas}{eje:lista}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introducción a \LaTeX
\item Texto con \LaTeX
\begin{itemize}
\item Reglas básicas
\item Entornos de texto
\begin{itemize}
\item Incisos, citaciones y poemas
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{quote}
\item \textsf{quotation}
\item \textsf{verse}
\end{itemize}
\item Listas
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{itemize}
\item \textsf{enumerate}
\item \textsf{description}
\end{itemize}
\item Texto alineado horizontalmente
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{flushleft}
\item \textsf{center}
\item \textsf{flushright}
\end{itemize}
\item Texto mecanografiado
\begin{itemize}
\item \textsf{verbatim}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{micodigo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think with `\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8}` and without `literate`, there's no problem with accented characters.

Comment: @Ignasi You're right. I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice solution, unfortunately that example is too long and doesn't fit in the page.

Answer (score 3):

listings cannot handle utf8 characters. Use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`. However, only two byte characters are possible.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]Tex}
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakautoindent=true,
    captionpos=t,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}  
\begin{itemize}
  \item Introducción a \LaTeX
  \item Texto con \LaTeX
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Reglas básicas
    \item Entornos de texto
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Incisos, citaciones y poemas
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \textsf{quote}
        \item \textsf{quotation}
        \item \textsf{verse}
      \end{itemize}
      \item Listas
     \begin{itemize}
        \item \textsf{itemize}
        \item \textsf{enumerate}
        \item \textsf{description}
      \end{itemize}
      \item Texto alineado horizontalmente
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \textsf{flushleft}
        \item \textsf{center}
        \item \textsf{flushright}
      \end{itemize}
      \item Texto mecanografiado
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \textsf{verbatim}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works with normal listings, but not with showexpl. The non-ascii-chars get lost when the tempory file is written.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: One can get the correct output by adding the literate-option to the explpreset key, but one still get errors. tcolorbox is certainly a better option than showexpl.