# How to use bold/colors in listling?

Tags: listings

I would like to emphasize words from code. Let us say code. How to do that? And is it possible even in case I load the code from a file? And is it possible to use diacritic?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc} 
\newcommand\tab[1][2cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  listing options={basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily},
  title={Soubor \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}


\newcommand{\listingsfont}{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Put your code here.
\end{lstlisting}

\mylisting[label=input]{Name}{in.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the emphasis follow a certain pattern (e.g. always color a certain keyword a certain color)? If so, `\lstset{emph={<your keyword here>},      emphstyle=\color{red},`  as described on page 19 of the `listings` documentation might help. [How to insert code with accents with listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30512/134144)  might also be interesting.

Comment: I would like to emphasis wholes lines not only particular words, I don't have certain keywords. Or is it possible to do a pattern according to the lines? I mean, I have 8 lines and I would like to emphasis the first, second and ninth.

Comment: Probably you can make use of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8860/134144 to change the color of a whole line of code.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, it will not in lstlisting mode? Could you please write a short example, I don't understand it.