# Have accented letter in keywords with listings

Tags: listings, accents

How can I have an word with accented latter that is also a keyword using `listings`?
I found a solution to have accented letters [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/how-to-insert-code-with-accents-with-listings), but if the keyword contains an accent, it is not recognized as a keyword.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}{morekeywords={normal, accentué}}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\small,
    inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
    literate={é}{{\'e}}1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=mylang]
notakeyword
normal
accentué
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

results in this, where `accentué` is not in bold:

[image]