# odd displays of accentuated characters in lstlisting environment

Tags: listings, unicode

when i try to write accentuated characters (éà...) in a **lstlisting** environment,

*hence :*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=bash,
    extendedchars=\true,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    classoffset=0,
    keywords={arg1},
    keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,
    classoffset=1,
    keywords={arg2},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    frame=boxshadow
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[title={syntaxe}]
$ ln -s arg1 arg2
arg1 : chemin (relatif ou absolu) du répertoire ou du fichier pointé
arg2 : chemin (relatif ou absolu) du lien à créer
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

> here's what i get :

### [image]

*note : it seems like the accentuated letters are placed before the non-accentuated ones.*

My document uses *UTF-8* encoding (from **texworks** settings)

I've tried to setup **lstset** setting **extendedchars** to *\true* and **inputencoding** to *utf8*. But this doesn't seem to apply any effects to the current code..

Comment: The accented `à` seems correct. Does the problem appear with any other character than `é`?

Comment: @T.Verron eèéàe is rendered as èéàee (it seems like the accentuated letters are placed before non-accentuated ones)

Comment: Duplicate of [Having problems with listings and UTF-8. Can it be fixed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed) (anyway I try adding the literate option for each character and it works)

Answer (score 1):

The `listings` package doesn't handle UTF-8, only one-byte characters.  You have to use the `listingsutf8` package, which works only with the `\lstinputlisting` command, not with the `lstlisting` environment.

You'll have to change the `inputencoding` option in your `\lstset` command such as:

```
\lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin9}
```

This is needed by the `listingsutf8` package to convert multibyte UTF-8 characters to one-byte characters.  As I suspect you're French, latin9 is a good choice.  For other languages, other one-byte character sets might be more appropriate.

Check `listingsutf8` documentation for details.

Comment: the same trouble occurs using this package.

Comment: You also need in your preamble: `\lstset{inputencoding=utf8/latin9}`

Comment: According to `listings` documentation, `utf8` encoding should be usable with `extendedchars=false`, that is by letting `inputenc` handle these chars instead of `listings`. While it indeed doesn't work in this very case, I wouldn't say it is a design choice.