# lstlisting and this symbol : █

Tags: symbols, listings

I want to know how to print this symbol "█" that I have in an external file loaded with listing.

Or at least how to print it with `\something`, cause it's not a blackbox.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}  % permet la cesure des mot accentue et des guillemets francais
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bold-extra}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

\title{Title}
\author{Lou}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
%
%\begin{abstract}
%\end{abstract}
%
\section{Introduction}
%
\paragraph{}
Nous avons par ailleurs illustré ce problème dans le code deadlock.c dont le code source est consultable à la fin de ce document. Voici un apperçu console de programme qui ne se termine donc pas.
\lstinputlisting[language=C]{file}
%
\end{document}
```

my other file "file" in the same directory content :
    blabla
    █

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) including a sample of the relevant part of the external file.

Comment: You are are using the Unicode symbol U+2588 (FULL BLOCK) but it's just defined to be a black square so you could use `\rule` or any other command to produce a square such as `\Box`

Comment: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2588}{\rule{.5em}{.5em}}` enables the character in normal text, listings seems to require more, I'll let someone with more experience of that package answer.

Comment: see this question for utf8 and listings http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99218/odd-displays-of-accentuated-characters-in-lstlisting-environment