# Unicode and listings - still no luck

Tags: xetex, listings, unicode

Although there are already some discussions on this issue, I can't get any of the proposed solutions to work for me.

Take this document and compile it with xelatex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,parskip=half+,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage{listings}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\lstset{
  breaklines=true,
  extendedchars=true,
  frame=single,
  keepspaces=true,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
}

\begin{document}
Test
\lstinputlisting[language=SQL,numbers=none,firstline=1,lastline=1]{code.sql}
Test
\lstinputlisting[language=SQL,numbers=none,firstline=2,lastline=2]{code.sql}
Test
\lstinputlisting[language=SQL,numbers=none,firstline=3,lastline=3]{code.sql}
Test
\lstinputlisting[language=SQL,numbers=none,firstline=4,lastline=4]{code.sql}

\end{document}
```

Code.sql:

```
Adélaïde de Maiziére
Mikuláš Frashëri
Petrė Meier
Şimşek Đurić
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

I tried the suggestion from [The 'listings' package and UTF-8](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8) and copied the given code into my document (do I maybe need to customize the hex-codes? What do they mean?). The result stays exactly the same.

Then, I tried the solution using literate from [Having problems with listings and UTF-8. Can it be fixed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed) by adding the following line:

```
literate={á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {Ş}{{\c S}}1 {ş}{{\c s}}1 {ć}{{\'c}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {Đ}{{D}}1 {š}{{s}}1,
```

The result (note the additional spacing in the first line and the incorrect handling of the other characters).
[image]

What can I do?

Comment: In my answer in your first link you need the extend the line `^^^^20ac^^^^0153^^^^0152% nouveau pour xetex` with more code. E.g. `^^^^20ac` is for the euro sign (U+20AC). For "s cedille" (U+015F) you would have to add   ^^^^015F. It is also possible to enter the chars directly `€Œœ% nouveau pour xetex`. The code works only if you use extendedchars=true!

Comment: Thanks!
Do you know if there is a way to make this work for combined characters, too (such as ę̐, ...)? I've switched to Arial Unicode MS and added the diacritical marks (^^^^0310^^^^0328) to the definition but they are not combined with the base character as Latex seems to insert a space between them.

Comment: I don't think that it can work with combined characters. Imho you will have to use literate for this.