# Can I include Chinese characters in listings? If so, how?

Tags: listings, unicode

I'd like to include Chinese characters in listings. Can it be done, and, if so, how?

Comment: This a starting point tip for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I enclose an example with a help of the [`listingsutf8`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listingsutf8) package and the [CODE2000](http://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm) font. I ran `xelatex` and `lualatex`, the result looks all the same.

```
%! {xe|lua}latex mal-cjkv.tex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mal-code.tex}
My source code and Good bye! in Japanese:  さよなら。
A greeting in Chinese: 你怎么样?
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
% http://web.archive.org/web/20101122142710/http://code2000.net/code2000_page.htm
\setmainfont{CODE2000.TTF}
\lstinputlisting{mal-code.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: You should specify which engine you used. Is it XeLaTeX?

Comment: @Jubobs I hope I did that in shebang, I ran both engines (xelatex, lualatex), the output looks all the same.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newfontfamily\cjk{Code2000}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
Some nonsense text with the  Libertine font.

\begin{Verbatim}[codes=\cjk,numbers=left,frame=single,label=Chinese test]
My source code and Good bye! in Japanese:  さよなら。
A greeting in Chinese: 你怎么样?
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`listings` package is rather special, Malipivo's solution works wrong when

1. We use syntax highlighting;
2. We mix CJK characters and Latin characters.

Here is an example which shows the problem.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{commentstyle=\color{blue},morecomment=[l]{//}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FandolSong-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

\section{Failure}
\begin{lstlisting}
// tomorrow明天
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

And here is the solution, using `xeCJK`:

[image]

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{commentstyle=\color{blue},morecomment=[l]{//}}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{FandolSong-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

\section{Success}
\begin{lstlisting}
// tomorrow明天
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here is a bug: There is a space between `明` and `天`. I don't think xeCJK wants to insert space between CJK characters, does it?

Comment: It is more likely a bug in `listings`: Adding `columns=fullflexible` in `\lstset` removed the extra spaces. Not sure why it would insert spaces between CJK but not latin characters.