# how to insert comment in lstlisting

Tags: listings, comments, listingsutf8

I have a problem with inserting a comment in lstlisting environment.

LaTeX says:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�\expandafter not set up
>   for use with LaTeX.
>
> See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
>
> Type H  for immediate help.
>
> ...
>
> l.49 \%komentář
>
> Your command was ignored.

I want the character % to start a comment which ends at end of line.

I tried `\lstset{morecomment=[l]\%}` but I get the error above.

Here is a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
...
\begin{document}
\lstset{
language=Matlab,
comment=[l]{\%}
}
...
\begin{lstlisting}[title=Výpočet]
%komentář
code
\end{lstlisting}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could use `fancyvrb` package as an alternative, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170346/48028

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).