# CJK and code highlighting

Tags: cjk

I need to add a JSON snippet that contains a few Japanese characters to my document. I'm able to use Japanese characters using CJK package and highlight my code using minted or lstlistings, but is there any way to use Japanese characters inside the highlighted code?

Comment: These answers might help, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170314/can-i-include-chinese-characters-in-listings-if-so-how/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pygments support Unicode well, you don't need special settings for that. Anyway, you should know how to use Japanese in LaTeX first. See [How to write Japanese with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15516/how-to-write-japanese-with-latex)

Both `luatexja` and (racent version of) `xeCJK` support `listings` package well. But with old `CJK` package, `listings` is much more difficult to use and is only partially supported.

BTW, there is no javascript language predefined in `listings` package. A previous question [language option supported in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89574/language-option-supported-in-listings) may help. In the following examples I use Java instead for simplicity.

### LuaLaTeX

LuaLaTeX with `luatexja` package is preferred.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{IPAexMincho} % A high quality Japanese font preinstalled in TeX Live

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{purple},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
if (b == true)
    s = "日本語";
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

### XeLaTeX

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{IPAexMincho}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{purple},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]
if (b == true)
    s = "日本語";
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

### pdfLaTeX

Using `CJK` package, we can use Japanese characters properly in the code if we escape to LaTeX.

```
% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  extendedchars=false,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{purple},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{ipxm}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=\#]
if (b == true)
    s = "#日本語#"; // No syntax highlighting anyway
\end{lstlisting}

\clearpage\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing the pdflatex escape thing before but it didn't work, but your example works. Not sure what I was doing wrong. Thanks a lot!