# lstlisting environment with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: listings, listingsutf8

I have a problem using `lstlisting` environment with utf8 encoding. I got this error

```
 Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�\expandafter not set up for use wit
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  {entête}.{informations}.{signature} 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed)