# Colored LaTeX command in verbatim

Tags: color, verbatim

MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{}
\end{document}
```

that I want

[image]

in verbatim. Always gets `Can be used only in preamble.` Is there a basic solve?

Comment: You wan't `listings` or something like that. You can't use a 2nd `\documentclass` in your document (at least not without much struggling ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I'll try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package; here's a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{maincs}{RGB}{177,0,39}
\definecolor{secondarycs}{RGB}{255,179,246}
\definecolor{tertiarycs}{RGB}{0,149,86}

\lstset{
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  columns=fullflexible,
  breaklines=true,
  texcsstyle=*\color{maincs},
  texcs={documentclass,begin,end,chapter},
  moretexcs=[2]{usepackage},
  texcsstyle=*[2]{\color{secondarycs!80!black}},
  moretexcs=[3]{maketitle,title,author,tableofcontents},
  texcsstyle=*[3]{\color{tertiarycs}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{}
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if `\chapter{Özgür}` like not working. Do you check it? @Gonzalo Medina.

Comment: @Özgür for an explanation and possible solutions, please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24528/3954

Comment: It is OK, working @Gonzalo Medina.