# polish characters ą

Tags: listings

I cannot get to work my special chars in listings, my texmaker is configurated to use utf8 in options, but I get error:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�\lst@FillFixed@ not set up for use
>   with LaTeX.

With XeLatex i dont get any errors but it doesn't show any ą in pdf. Could i import the content of file.txt and show it in C# colors without copy-paste to .tex file?

```
\documentclass[titlepage, a4paper]{mwart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{sharpc}{language=[Sharp]C, frame=lr, rulecolor=\color{blue!80!black}}
\begin{document}
ą
\begin{lstlisting}
ą
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: For future readers, if any: See [unicode - Having problems with listings and UTF-8. Can it be fixed? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed)  for pdflatex / https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25391/the-listings-package-and-utf-8?noredirect=1&lq=1for other engines.

Answer (score 2):

From [Section 2.5 of documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)
simply use

```
\begin{lstlisting}[extendedchars=false]
ą
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try it in an utf8 encoded file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, yes.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had used true, and not false. Well this will not give an error, but try out `ą and some more text` (in one line)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, a new line appears. I'm afraid I would have to delete the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use literate to replace the char with a suitable command:

```
\documentclass[titlepage, a4paper]{mwart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{sharpc}{language=[Sharp]C, frame=lr, rulecolor=\color{blue!80!black}}

\lstset{literate=%
    {ą}{{\k a}}1    
}
\begin{document}
ą 
\begin{lstlisting}
ą
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `1` in the code?

Comment: The number of chars the replacement will produce.