# An error appears saying that utf8 and listing are not compatible

Tags: listings, listingsutf8

If I compile the next code the following error appear.

! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�\expandafter\lst@FillFixed@\fi not 
set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.6 ...%% sI A tiene inversa  esta es la soluci�n(
                                                  Vector Nulo)
?

Then when I comment "\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}" the code compile, but I need the utf8 package. How could I fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}




\usepackage{listings}



\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{txfonts,pxfonts}


\begin{document}    



\section*{Matlab Code}
\begin{lstlisting}
clc, clear
syms k1 k2 y m
A= [0 1 0 1;-1*(k1+k2)/m 0 k2/m 0; 0 0 0 1; k2/m 0 0 -(k1+k2)/m];
cero=zeros(4);  
determinante=det(A); %% Determinante de A
Sol=A\cero;%% sI A tiene inversa  esta es la solución(Vector Nulo)
% El unico punto de equilibrio es el punto 0
detervalprop= det(A-y*eye(4))
[V,D]=eig(A)
f=subs(D(1),m,1)
%figure
%ezsurf(f)
%figure
%subplot(2,1,2)
h=ezplot(f)
set(h, 'Color', 'r')
\end{lstlisting}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you read the manual for listingsutf8? It can only help in a very certain case. I generally recommend our users to document in English to avoid this. You can get by by using the literal trick this is documented elsewhere on the site (there should be enough questions about listings vs uft8)

Comment: If you had read the manual you would know that listingsutf8 **only** helps on `\lstinputlisting` it cannot help on the use of the `lstlisting` env like you use here.

Comment: @daleif I havent found the "enough" questions that you are talking about, I have just find one, and is this one "tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110020/utf8-for-listings";, but this have'nt answer my specific problem. If I get well your message, are you saing that my answer is in the manual of "listingsutf8"?

Comment: Here is one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24532/3929, the option is literate, there are many more questions and answers if you google "listings utf8"

Comment: Yes @daleif you are right , I haven't found an answer reading all this documentation that is why Im posting, could you send me a code please, where I can see what I have to modify?.

Comment: Not at a computer so no. Have you tried placing your code in an external file and including it with `\lstinputlisting ` because the `listingsutf8 ` should work, do remember to read the manual for that package. Generally I don't recommend to include the source code directly into the tex code, as you can very easily forget to update it. Much better to keep it external such that the code you include is the same that you use for what ever it is you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can accept to `escape` to LaTeX for accented characters.

From page 15 in `listings` manual:

> Similarly, if you are using UTF-8 extended characters in a listing,
>   they must be placed within an escape to LaTeX.

Note: I've commented `mcode` because MikTeX didn't find it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{listings}

%\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{txfonts,pxfonts}


\begin{document}    

\section*{Matlab Code}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=&]
clc, clear
syms k1 k2 y m
A= [0 1 0 1;-1*(k1+k2)/m 0 k2/m 0; 0 0 0 1; k2/m 0 0 -(k1+k2)/m];
cero=zeros(4);  
determinante=det(A); %% Determinante de A
Sol=A\cero;%% si A tiene inversa  esta es la soluci&ó&n (Vector Nulo)
% El &ú&nico punto de equilibrio es el punto 0
detervalprop= det(A-y*eye(4))
[V,D]=eig(A)
f=subs(D(1),m,1)
%figure
%ezsurf(f)
%figure
%subplot(2,1,2)
h=ezplot(f)
set(h, 'Color', 'r')
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What I usually have in my `lstlisting` setup is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    inputencoding = utf8,  % Input encoding
    extendedchars = true,  % Extended ASCII
    texcl         = true,  % Activate LaTeX commands in comments
    mathescape    = true   % Mathematical expressions between $
    captionpos    = b,     % Caption position
    literate      =        % Support additional characters
      {á}{{\'a}}1  {é}{{\'e}}1  {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1  {ú}{{\'u}}1
      {Á}{{\'A}}1  {É}{{\'E}}1  {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1  {Ú}{{\'U}}1
      {à}{{\`a}}1  {è}{{\`e}}1  {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1  {ù}{{\`u}}1
      {À}{{\`A}}1  {È}{{\'E}}1  {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1  {Ù}{{\`U}}1
      {ä}{{\"a}}1  {ë}{{\"e}}1  {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1  {ü}{{\"u}}1
      {Ä}{{\"A}}1  {Ë}{{\"E}}1  {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1  {Ü}{{\"U}}1
      {â}{{\^a}}1  {ê}{{\^e}}1  {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1  {û}{{\^u}}1
      {Â}{{\^A}}1  {Ê}{{\^E}}1  {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1  {Û}{{\^U}}1
      {œ}{{\oe}}1  {Œ}{{\OE}}1  {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1  {ß}{{\ss}}1
      {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1  {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
      {ñ}{{\~n}}1  {Ñ}{{\~N}}1  {¿}{{?`}}1  {¡}{{!`}}1
      % ¿ and ¡ are not correctly displayed if inconsolata font is used
      % together with the lstlisting environment. Consider typing code in
      % external files and using \lstinputlisting to display them instead.      
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
/* 
    comentarios en español
    código base
*/
a = a + 1
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

...and it works quite well for Spanish and Italian and a handful of other latin scripts.

[image]

Comment: The thing is that if I eliminate de package UTF8, all my code compile find, and even the listing appear how i wanted, it is in the elegant format that Matlab have. Your answer looks finds, but it is not weird to write all those symbols in a Tex?

Comment: I really do not understand the comment, sorry. You can copy that `lstset` and put it in a style file --- the matter is that `lstlisting`, by default, is not set-up to work with characters that are not ASCII in the inline environment. This snippet will solve this.  Using `\lstinputlisting` should work out of the box...