# Include files with different input encoding

Tags: include, input-encodings

How can I `include` a "~.tex"-file with a different input encoding? I use UTF-8 encoding in my main file but have to include a file with ISO-8859-1 encoding (sink output of RStudio, see also related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955337/use-sink-with-utf-8-encoding)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\include{Umlaute}       % ISO-8859-1 encoding

\end{document}
```

(to be processed by luatex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 8-bit TeX engines (pdfTeX, TeX)

`\inputencoding` from package `inputenc` can also be used inside the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\inputencoding{latin1}
\include{Umlaute}       % ISO-8859-1 encoding
\inputencoding{utf8} % back to UTF-8

\end{document}
```

## XeTeX

The input encoding can be specified with `\XeTeXinputencoding` in the correct file. Thus, `Umlaute.tex` starts with:

```
% Umlaute.tex
\XeTeXinputencoding ISO-8859-1
```

The syntax of `\XeTeXinputencoding` is quite obscure (missing documentation).
From the source code:

- The argument is scanned like a file name.
- It can be surrounded by single or double quotes.
- Then the name (without quotes) is checked in a case insensitive manner
  against the strings `auto`, `utf8`, `utf16`, `utf16be`, `utf16le`, `bytes`.
  (Source: `XeTeX_ext.c`, method `getencodingmodeandinfo`).
  If the name is not such a predefined name, then the name is passed to `ucnv_open` (ICU converter). From its [documentation](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucnv_8h.html#a485c78d4149165f504effa2287717e41):

  > The actual name will be resolved with the alias file using a case-insensitive string comparison that ignores leading zeroes and all non-alphanumeric characters. E.g., the names `UTF8`, `utf-8`, `u*T@f08` and `Utf 8` are all equivalent.

The previous version with curly braces has worked, because the name was not a predefined name, but was passed to `ucnv_open`, which filtered the curly braces out. Also the funny `\XeTeXinputencoding}ISO-88;591{` would have worked.

## Unicode-Engines (LuaTeX, XeTeX)

I would recode the non-UTF-8 files, e.g. (bash/linux):

```bash
recode latin1..utf8 Umlaute.tex
```

Comment: Any advantage of `recode` over `iconv`? (just wondering)

Comment: Are you sure `\XeTeXinputencoding` wants braces?

Comment: @egreg `\XeTeXinputencoding` removes single and double quotes around the name. If the name is not a predefined name (see updated answer), then non-alphanumeric characters are filtered out, including curly braces.

Comment: @daleif `recode latin1..utf8` is shorter than `iconv -f latin1 -t utf8`.

Answer (score 1):

I never got the "*inputencoding*"-method to work for my external text file. If you look at the link below you can see the code I used for adding support to Swedish and German characters (åäö üß) as well as Portuguese characters read from an external text file.

Link: [Having problems with listings and UTF-8. Can it be fixed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed)