# How can I typeset "è" by typing "\`e" in source code inside a lstlisting environment?

Tags: listings, unicode

i know that this answer is a duplicate but the solution proposed to other question doesn't work for me.

So, i declared my language and my style and then add a "literate={è}{{\`{e}}}{1}" (or "literate={è}{{\`e}}1", i tried a lot of combinations)  to use "\`e" as "e" accented. But this doesn't work for me.
for example:

```
\lstset{
   language=Arduino,
   style=myArduino,
   literate={è}{{\`{e}}}{1},
}
```

and then:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=myArduino, caption="funzione "loop", captionpos=b]
    // quando il bluetooth \`e connesso posso procedere ad inizializzare...
\end{lstlisting}
```

that should produce an output with the "\`e" substituted by the è, but that doesn't happen and i get "\`e" as output.

now, how i can write the accented letters like "\`e" and get the è as output?

(i have an english keyboard that don't have accented letters)

thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `quando il bluetooth è connesso`. The purpose of `literate` is to transform `è` into ``\`e``, not conversely.

Comment: Any keyboard is capable of producing `è`

Comment: sorry, in common latex i use \\`e as è, but in lstlisting it doesn't work, i can't produce the è with my keyboard and i can't copy past it every time. there is a solution for this?

Comment: What strange keyboard is it?

Comment: i have this layout.. https://goo.gl/images/1NyniX

Comment: It's necessary to know what operating system you are on.

Comment: windows, so the there isn't a method to use \\`e as è without changing the layout of the keyboard? i tried to use "literate" to transform \\`e in è, but i get weird errors.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/110605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `escapeinside` feature

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines = true, frame = trBL, tabsize = 4, basicstyle = \small \ttfamily, keywordstyle = \color{blue}, stringstyle = \color{red}, rulecolor = \color{black}}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = Python, caption = funzione ``loop", captionpos = b, escapeinside = {(*@}{@*)}]
mellin_parameter = {'number_of_gl_points': 8, 'x_axis_intersection': 1.9, 'phi': (3.0 * numpy.pi) / 4.0, 'extension': False}
with open(input_path.replace('pretable/', 'mellin_parameter.pickle'), 'wb') as pf:
    pickle.dump(mellin_parameter, pf) ## accented (*@ \`{e} @*)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

which would produce

> [image: escape in lstlisting]

Comment: i resolved the issue using a text editor and replacing the \\`e with the è, but this is a good method to do it within latex. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [Having problems with listings and UTF-8. Can it be fixed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed#comment1445831_24544) using escapeinside doesn't work well with the format.

You can simply use (remember to escape the backslash)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines = true, frame = trBL, tabsize = 4, basicstyle = \small \ttfamily, keywordstyle = \color{blue}, stringstyle = \color{red}, rulecolor = \color{black}}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = Python, caption = funzione ``loop", captionpos = b,
literate=
{\\`e}{{\`e}}1
]
mellin_parameter = {'number_of_gl_points': 8, 'x_axis_intersection': 1.9, 'phi': (3.0 * numpy.pi) / 4.0, 'extension': False}
with open(input_path.replace('pretable/', 'mellin_parameter.pickle'), 'wb') as pf:
    pickle.dump(mellin_parameter, pf) ## accented \`e
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively since this is not really LaTeX code you can also specify that the backslash is not necessary

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{breaklines = true, frame = trBL, tabsize = 4, basicstyle = \small \ttfamily, keywordstyle = \color{blue}, stringstyle = \color{red}, rulecolor = \color{black}}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language = Python, caption = funzione ``loop", captionpos = b,
literate=
{`e}{{\`e}}1
]
mellin_parameter = {'number_of_gl_points': 8, 'x_axis_intersection': 1.9, 'phi': (3.0 * numpy.pi) / 4.0, 'extension': False}
with open(input_path.replace('pretable/', 'mellin_parameter.pickle'), 'wb') as pf:
    pickle.dump(mellin_parameter, pf) ## accented `e
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output is as you expect (note that the `è` is italicized)

[image: output]