# Special characters in formatted code

Tags: listings, unicode, code

I want to show some nicely formatted source code, e.g.:

```
er ist ein bisschen ein ötto geworden
```

My document:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
Ünnormal diggi hä
\lstinputlisting[language = python]{testinclude.txt}
\end{document}
```

The text outside the listing works, but the txt file produces the error `Package utf8x Error: Character182appearedalone.`

How do I show code that contains special characters?

Like [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed) suggested, I tried escaping the ö or setting a literate to `\''o`, but both times I only got this in utf8 and utf8x: [image: weird looking ö]

Comment: try with utf8 instead of utf8x. If you still get errors you should show the content of the file you are trying to include.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer with utf8, I get `Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "B6`. I edited the question to show the input file.

Comment: You need to make sure that both files, your .tex file and the file that you want to include, are in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Jasper VS code shows both are in UTF-8 Encoding.

Comment: The correct way to escape `ö` is not `\''o` but `\"o`.