# How can I write letters like ř, í, á to listings?

Tags: listings, utf8

How can I write letters like ř, í, á to listings?

Why is zero in the name of the section?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[total={7in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{listings}



\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[auto counter,list inside=lol,list type={lstlisting}]{\mylisting}[3][]{%
  listing file={#3},
  title=Listing,
  colback=white,
  colframe=gray!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  listing only,
  breakable,
  listing options={basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{purple},
  },
  title={Script \thetcbcounter: #2},
  #1
}
\newcommand{\listingsfont}{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\section{Why is here 0}
\lstset{morecomment=[l]{\#}}
\mylisting{Code}{script.txt}

\end{document}
```

The file with the script:

```
script.txt
#hello
í ů ř á
hello
```

Comment: with pdflatex you can use literate see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `report` class. First sectioning level of `report` (and `book`) class is chapter and not section. Therefore you are getting a zero in your section number. Use `article` class or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26958503/11358511).

Using `listing options` was for some reasons producing weird results, but if you instead use `\lstset`; you will get the desired output.

Also the argument structure can be simplified as in the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myscript.txt}
script.txt
# hello
í ů ř á
hello
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbinputlisting[%
  auto counter,%
  list inside=lol,%
  list type={lstlisting}%
  ]%
  {\mylisting}%
  [2]{%
  listing file={#1},%
  title=Listing,%
  colback=white,%
  colframe=gray!75!black,%
  fonttitle=\bfseries,%
  listing only,%
  breakable,%
  title={Script \thetcbcounter: #2},%
}

\begin{document}
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,%
  commentstyle=\color{purple},% Not working :(
  morecomment=[l]{\#}%
}
\section{There is no zero here}
\mylisting{myscript.txt}{My script}
\end{document}
```

Note: `pdflatex` will complain about UTF characters, you would need to use Xe/LuaLaTeX.

[image: 1]

Comment: Sorry I just realized that the comment isn't colored and I have no clue why. I pass on this.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Comment: Have you figured out the colour comment, please?

Comment: It should ideally work, but maybe something is wrong with the combination of tcolorbox and listings. Try for example this https://pastebin.com/yA0kzuyw. It works as expected. It might be better to 1) ask a separate question so that experts can find a way to deal with the specific problem we are facing or 2) report a bug to the maintainer of package `listings` or `tcolorbox`.

Comment: It work after %. How to set that comments are after #?

Comment: I didn't understand this, can you please edit your question to exemplify what you mean?